# Closest pair of points brute-force; Why O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, performance, closest-points

I feel stupid for asking this question, but...

For the "closest pair of points" problem (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) if unfamiliar with it), why is the worst-case running time of the brute-force algorithm O(n^2)?

If say n = 4, then there would only be 12 possible pair of points to compare in the search space, if we also consider comparing two points from either direction. If we don't compare two points twice, then it's going to be 6.

O(n^2) doesn't add up to me.

Comment: How about `n=3`? And how about `n=5`?

Comment: The number of steps is proportional to O(n ^ 2), they don't have to be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual number of comparisons is:

[image: exact formula], or [image].

But, in big-O notation, you are only concerned about the dominant term.  At very large values of [image], the [image] term becomes less important, as does the [image] coefficient on the [image: <code>n^2</code>] term.  So, we just say it's [image: <code>O(n^2)</code>].

Big-O notation isn't meant to give you the exact formula for the time taken or number of steps.  It only gives you the order of the complexity/time so you can get a sense of how it scales for large inputs.

Comment: And the reason we don't care about the coefficient is that we can always buy/build a computer that is faster or slower by a constant factor. Or we can just be that much more patient. :)

Comment: Great point.  Also, you can easily get a factor of 2 difference between a good implementation and a bad implementation of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

In big-O notation, you can factor out multiplied constants, so:

```
O(k*(n^2)) = O(n^2)
```

The idea is that the constant (1/2 in the OP example, since distance comparison is reflective) doesn't really tell us anything new about the complexity.  It still gets bigger with the square of the input.

Answer (score 1):

In the brute-force version of the algorithm you compare all possible pairs of points. For each of `n` points you have `(n - 1)` other points to compare and if we take every pair once we end up with `(n * (n - 1)) / 2` comparisons. The pessimistic complexity of `O(n^2)` means that the number of operations is bound by `k * n^2` for some constant `k`. Big O notation can't tell you the exact number of operations but a function to which it is proportional when the size of data (`n`) increases.

Answer (score 1):

Applying brute force, we are forced to check all the possible pairs.Assuming N points,for each point there are N-1 other points for which we need to calculate the distance. So total possible distances calculated = N points * N-1 other points. But in process we double counted distances. Distance between A to B remains whether A to B  or B to A is calculated. Hence N*(N-1)/2. Hence O(N^2).